# Excel 2010 data validation to check if cell contain comma value

Tags: excel, vba

In excel 2010, how to do a validation if cell contain ',' then pop up a message to user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid unnecessary loop use below code.

```
Sub findComma()

    Dim srcRng As Range, findRng As Range
    Dim firstCell As String

    Dim lrow As Integer

    lrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srcRng = Range("A1:A" & lrow)
    Set findRng = srcRng.Find(What:=",", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)


    If Not findRng Is Nothing Then firstCell = findRng.Address

    Do Until findRng Is Nothing


        MsgBox (findRng.Address & " contains Comma ")
        findRng.Interior.Color = vbRed

        Set findRng = srcRng.FindNext(findRng)

        If findRng.Address = firstCell Then Exit Sub

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to apply validation on columns B,C AND E how to modify the code ?

Comment: @user1902849  Change this `Set srcRng = Range("A1:E" & lrow)` to apply validations on columns A, B , C, D & E

Comment: @user1902849  If you want only columns B,C & E then change this `Set srcRng = Union(Range("B1:C" & lrow), Range("E1:E" & lrow))`

Comment: Yes it works. Now I want to set entire excel sheet to white color, below is my code but got error return from the system

Comment: Sub DefaultFill()

Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim erange As Range

lastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
erange = ActiveSheet.Range("a1", ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
erange.Interior.Color = vbWhite

End Sub

Comment: @user1902849 `Cells.Interior.Color = vbWhite` try this

Comment: this code will make the border also in white..I want to maintain the border line as default black color

Answer (score 1):

Please try to show your work ..

lets say Column A contains the data then below code work perfectly

this is what u wanted (TESTED)

```
Sub tested()
Dim erange As Range
Dim lrow As Integer

lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each erange In Range("A2:A" & lrow)

If InStr(erange.Value, ",") > 0 Then

MsgBox (erange.Address & " contains Comma ")

erange.Interior.Color = vbRed

End If

Next erange

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to apply validation on columns B,C AND E how to modify the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Using normal data validation, you could try this

```
=(LEN(A1) = LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))
```